# MongoDB query KeyError

Tags: python, database, mongodb, csv, pymongo

I just started using MongoDB, and I've been trying to compare a huge csv list of identifiers with a a database in MongoDB. 
The thing is that depending on the csv file the code works or it doesn't. The csv is just a one column list of identifiers.

Here is my code:

```
import pymongo
import csv
from pymongo import MongoClient

connection = MongoClient()
db = connection.smth
collection1 = db.smth2
collection2 = db.smth3
writer = csv.writer(open("/Users/joseantonioruizgarcia/Desktop/OrgIdresult.csv", "w"))

with open('query_result.csv') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in spamreader:
        cursor1 = collection1.find({"_id" : row[0]})
        for document in cursor1:
            cursor2 = collection2.find({"ultimateParentId" : document['orgId']})
            for document2 in cursor2:
                writer.writerow([document2['name']])
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MongoDBconnect.py", line 18, in <module>
    cursor2 = collection2.find({"ultimateParentId" : document['orgId']})
KeyError: 'orgId'
```

The thing is that 'orgId' actually exists in the database, and when I use a different file it works, but I have to make it work with all files...

Any ideas?
Thanks!!

Comment: try simple to `print(document)` and you will see what do you have there, maybe some times it is empty, i don't know

Comment: It would be nice viewing how is your .csv. Maybe you've got some hidden lines or something.

Comment: The problem is not the csv, it is just a list of identifiers.

Comment: Really no one has an answer to this?